# Flutter Patrol CLI - Xcode build error after Xcode update to version 14.3

Tags: flutter, flutter-patrol

After updating Xcode, the build for the integration tests fails.

I get the following error:

```
2023-05-04 10:02:20.872 xcodebuild[42145:1120855] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)

2023-05-04 10:02:21.858 xcodebuild[42145:1120855] [MT] IDEFileReferenceDebug: [Load] <IDESwiftPackageCore.IDESwiftPackageSpecialFolderFileReference, 0x600002d22700: name:Documentation.docc path:group:Documentation.docc> Failed to load container at path: ***/SourcePackages/checkouts/DefaultsWrapper/Sources/DefaultsWrapper/Documentation.docc, Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6 "Cannot open "Documentation.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot open "Documentation.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder".}   

2023-05-04 10:02:28.556 xcodebuild[42145:1120855] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/2c/fygq9xv55xxf_15bxz5gpkq89jvsyx/T/ResultBundle_2023-04-05_10-02-0028.xcresult         xcodebuild: error: Failed writing xctestrun file: The folder “Runner_iphonesimulator16.4.xctestrun” doesn’t exist..
```

Only the integration tests do not work since the update. However, the app can be launched normally.

**Version**:

```
patrol_cli v1.1.7
```

**Command**:

```
patrol test \
\--target integration_test/app_test.dart \
\--dart-define=ENVIRONMENT=dev
```

**Flutter Doctor Output:**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.18.4/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at
      /Users/***/fvm/versions/stable. Consider adding /Users/***/fvm/versions/stable/bin to the front of your path.
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: Have you figured this one out @Florian?

Comment: Hi, did you try running with --verbose?

Comment: I have the same problem :/